# Facebook Friend Dialog Replacement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Looking for a way to add a friend using the Facebook API. (Add Friend Request)

Seems on April 30th the Friends Dialog was https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog "The friends dialog is no longer available."

Even though in the API docs it says "The Friends Dialog should be used if you want to integrate the ability to add someone as a friend in your app." 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends

Does anyone know of an alternative to this using the API or a dialog? Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Just got bitten by this today.  If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them!  The best I've come up with so far is to provide instructions to a user regarding how to add a friend on Facebook, and linking to the desired friend's profile, hoping the user figures it out.  How is this an improvement in UX, Facebook?

Comment: @rinogo is it still the same? Or is there a better solution now?

Comment: Not that I know of :/ but if you find anything, please report back! :)

Comment: @user1463822 any luck with this yet?

Comment: @rinogo any luck with this yet?

Comment: @Jaysbays, I don't think there have been any changes to the API that would make this possible. :/